# How to change text file extension type in Linux?

Tags: linux, gedit

Using gedit, I want to create a config.env file, how do I change the extension as simply naming it config.env doesn't work.

THanks in advance

Comment: This question is better placed on https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com. Speaking of the actual question, I cannot reproduce the problem. Please add details on your GNOME version and Linux distribution. Also make some screenshots.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really doesn't matter  what the file extension is, as long as it is in a linux machine.
Just execute `file <filename>` to know the file type.

However you could try this:

Save the file as it is like config.txt or other and execute the below command

```
mv config.txt config.env
```

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)